# I want to make a dhcp server on the raspberry pi however it seems to not work while I have the dhcp client running

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

When I use both the rpi dhcp client to get static IPs or dhcp IPs for my interfaces and then use that information for  a dhcp server , I get a ton of errors when checking the status . The only semi solution I seemed to find was remove the dchp client and set static IPs in the /etc/network/interfaces file but that file didnt seem to work with dhcp.

The error  I get in the status is `failed to start lsb dhcp server` yet there is acc no code errors in the config file because it wokrs when restarted and on reboot it doesnt work.

```
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-09-07 04:59:48 EDT; 2min 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 628 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you can't have two DHCP servers on your LAN, so how could a DHCP client ever work as a DHCP server (for the same subnet). Having two DHCP servers leads to complete confusion as one server won't know what addresses have been leased by the other. That will lead to address conflicts. DHCP servers have to have a fixed IP address.

Comment: The DHCP needs to have a static IP config. It should be your network's authority on IP addresses and should not rely on other DHCP servers since more than one of them WILL lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable dhcpcd completely, and enable the internal debian networking.  Then go into the /etc/network/interface.d

create a file for EVERY NIC

Set the dhcp option inside the relevant network adapter.

I don't have the exact command with me.